# How to update a document without causing a write firestore?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a billing web app where users update stock of an item frequently. So it will cost me much. Is there a way to only update the stock without causing a document write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no

Long answer: most likely not

Each document updated will count as a document write for billing on Firestore. Even if you try to bundle multiple updates into a single batch call.

One suggestion would be to throttle updates on the client side to slow down rapid updates. This will however affect the accuracy of the data your end users will get while using the app. Example of throttling: [Small article on throtting/debouncing](https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-throttling-and-debouncing-973131c1ba07)

Another suggestion is to avoid making updates that are meaningless.

You can check if a value isn't going to change or if the value change isn't important before trying to do an update:

```
function updateValue(newValue) {
    // Check if value has changed
    if (newValue === value) {
        // pass
        return;
    }

    // make an update request
    // ...
}
```

Any other suggested solution would require your end users sharing the same network or introducing another service outside of Firestore.

Last thing to consider is that maybe it's too soon to consider billing. Firestore is pretty cheap for what it offers. Here's a good video by Firebase about billing:

[Firebase video on Getting to know pricing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NegFl9p_sE)

If none of these suggestions has been helpful, I'd recommend adding some code examples, etc for better suggestions :)

Comment: Thank you sir, I am just a student and new to database coding. I am doing a start-up. I watched a video by fireship.io about "how not to get a $30,000 bill by firebase, so I was sacred. Namaste